# installshield 2012 LE and windows service for windows 2008 r2 64 bit VS.NEt 2012

Tags: installshield-le

I have windows service developed by VS.Net 2012 , Windows 7 32 bit and installshield 2012 LE for setup.
In the development machine everything going well ,installation completed and service working fine .
When  upload  it to the server (windows server 2008 R2 SP1 64bit) during the installation , installation stopped and rolled back because of error 1001 .

Advise Please

Comment: I was having this problem also and I actually found the exact setting you have to change in InstallShield LE. I wrote it up how to fix it at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949860/error-1001-when-installing-custom-windows-service/38269757#38269757

Answer (score 1):

You're in a rough spot. Error 1001 comes from an InstallerClass, which uses a very fragile technology. The error 1001 has many different possible sources, ranging from an unhandled exception to what feels like the phase of the moon. However InstallShield LE doesn't really support installing services any other way.

The best advice I can offer is to use Windows Installer support for installing services. But in order to do that you will have to use a different installation creator. If you want to stick with InstallShield, the Professional edition has a view in which you can configure the Windows Installer support for services.

Comment: Augmentation my friend, augmentation. :)

Comment: Note that InstallShield 2013 LE added support for 64-bit file and registry locations, as well as services. So while the answer is still correct or the older version, the newer version changes things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Installer XML (WiX) to author a merge module that installs a windows service and then consume that merge module in a InstallShield LE project.  See:

[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Windows Services](http://blog.iswix.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

Installshield LE 2012 doesn't support 64bit.

There is a new beta available of Installshield LE that is supposed to add this feature: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/08/15/what-s-new-in-visual-studio-2013-and-installshield-limited-edition.aspx

It's also supposed to support the proper Windows Installer for installing services now, even in the LE (via "3 Configure the Target System" -> Services"). However I've not been able to get that bit working yet - maybe there's some magic setting I've missed.

You could try using this version - let me know if you have any luck getting it working via the proper windows installer services!